# I encounter this after running sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I encounter the following error after running `sudo apt upgrade` in Ubuntu 22.04:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generi
c:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic depends on linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26; howev
er:
  Package linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message ind
icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems pr
event configuration of linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic; howe
ver:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26
 linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: @user535733 this answer solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The key phrase in the error message is `package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration`

Reinstall the problematic package using `sudo apt install --reinstall <package-name>`

So, in your case, that would be `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-26`